# Como passar linhas de um DataGridView para outro?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Desejo passar as linhas selecionadas de um *datagrid* para outro, por exemplo, seleciono as linhas, clico num *button*, e elas passam para um outro. É fazer um adicionar - remover itens.

Tenho dois *datagrids*, um receberá *Produtos*, e o outro será para adicionar os produtos que deseja referenciar. O *button* será para adicionar estes itens selecionados no outro *grid*. Estou preenchendo esse primeiro *grid* com um `DataAdapter`/`DataTable`.

Segue: 
DG1 | Button | DG2

itens - Clicar-> .. 
            .. itens

-Sair daqui --> Para cá.

Answer (score 5):

Entao, podes tentar desse jeito:

Assumindo que seus produtos possuam um ID único, sugiro utilizar uma coluna do tipo `CheckBox` no `DataGridView`. Utilize o evento da `DataGrid "Cell Content Click"` para verificar se a coluna clicada foi a do `CheckBox` `(e.ColumnIndex == 0)`, sendo 'e' o `DataGridViewCellEventArgs` do evento.

Se for, 
atribua o valor 1 para ele (`dataGridViewMovimentos.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value = 1;`).

```
private void dataGridViewMovimentos_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.columnIndex == 0)
    {
        if(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridViewMovimentos.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value) == 0)
        {
            valorTransferencia += Convert.ToDouble(dataGridViewMovimentos.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value);
            txtBoxTotalTransferencia.Text = valorTransferencia.ToString();
            dataGridViewMovimentos.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            valorTransferencia += Convert.ToDouble(dataGridViewMovimentos.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value);
            txtBoxTotalTransferencia.Text = valorTransferencia.ToString();
            dataGridViewMovimentos.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

(Algumas coisas ai, como o valor, são utilizadas no meu programa. Então podes ignorar. A imagem é só para referencia. A parte importante são os Ifs e a alteração do Value da célula).

Depois, adicione ao evento click do botão a rotina abaixo para verificar todas as linhas e, quando encontrar um `CheckBox` com o valor 1, copiar aquela linha para a outra coluna(Sugiro utilizar o ID do produto na ultima posição da tabela, com a propriedade `visible = false`).

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        dataGridView2.Rows.Add(adicionar(row));
    }
}

private DataGridViewRow adicionar(DataGridViewRow row)
{
    DataGridViewRow newRow = (DataGridViewRow)row.Clone();
    newRow.Cells[1].Valeu = row.Cells[1].Value;
    newRow.Cells[2].Valeu = row.Cells[2].Value;
    newRow.Cells.Remove(newRow.Cells[0]);
    return newRow;
}
```

(Tens que fazer o `newRow.Cells[posicao].value` para cada célula que quiseres transferir e o remove para aquelas que quiseres remover.

Lembre-se de que a tua `DataGrid` destino tem que ter exatamente as mesmas colunas que a linha que estiveres retornando. Então faça o Remove onde precisar.
Tente fazer desse jeito ai. Testei aqui e funcionou.

P.s: Essa é a minha tela com a `CheckBox` no inicio:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Prefira postar o código aqui ao invés da *screenshot* dele. A *screenshot* do resultado é legal. Quando você mantém o código com 4 espaços em todas as linhas, ele formata e faz highlight.

Comment: Beleza @bigow. Comecei ontem, e ainda não tive tempo de estudar como funciona a formatação do site. tava postando o código, mas ele não tava ficando formatado. Daí, pra melhorar a visualização, coloquei a screenshot.

Comment: Usa quatro espaços no começo de cada linha ou um TAB antes de copiar que tudo se resolve. Você pode por <!-- language: c# --> uma linha antes do código, separado por uma linha em branco, para fazer as cores no código.

Answer (score 0):

Há varias maneiras de o fazer, dependendo dos objetos que as datagrids usam.

Como não dás mais detalhes, assumindo que tens 2 datagrids iguais:

- usar a mesma lista de objetos para as 2 datagrids
- adicionar uma propriedade a este objeto que define se este pertence 'a grid 1 ou 2 (com apenas 2 datagrids, tipo boolean será suficiente)
- usar esta propriedade para definir a visibilidade da linha em ambas as datagrids
- o botão inverte apenas a propriedade